# EPUB reader in Debian

Tags: linux, debian

I have one ebook in epub format, I tried to open it, but I was not satisfied with that what I found. Does someone know how to open epub document in Debian ?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming [within the scope defined by the community](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found solution, there is one library called Calibre. After installing, I am able to open epub document.

Installation with command (debian):

```
apt-get install calibre
```

Comment: After installing calibre you can just run `ebook-viewer` instead of the full software for reading ebooks.

Comment: For me, the best feature is that it allows to print e-book in PDF.

Answer (score 21):

Here's [a blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190620113533/http://xmodulo.com/good-epub-reader-linux.html) which gives a lists with various alternatives solutions.

1. Calibre
2. FBReader
3. Cool Reader
4. Okular (need to install okular-extra-backends pakage too)
5. pPub
6. epub
7. Sigil

Comment: Also very helpful answer as it lists alternatives. I didn't find anything said but at least `calibre`.

Comment: For Okular on Debian, you should `sudo apt install okular-extra-backends`

Answer (score 3):

An addition to lamanux's list of readers: I have found [Lucidor](https://alternativeto.net/software/lucidor/about/). Lightweight and simple screen. It seems to be useful. You can try. I moved from FBreader to Lucidor.